# Create a file in %temp% using C program

Tags: c, winapi

How to create a file in %temp% folder using C program. Please provide me some Ideas on it.

I am programming in windows using Mingw.

Update:

I want the file to be in .log or .txt format. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + `GetTempFilename`

Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I want the file name to be in .log or .txt format. How to do that?

Comment: @user1317084 They don't have specific formats. If you want a specific extension, you need to use a specific file name (and loose the auto generation from `GetTempFileName()`)

Comment: @Deanna thanks. I did the same as you said. I skipped GetTempFileName().

Answer (score 4):

You can use Windows API GetTempPath() (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx ), build full path and then either use Win API or C functions to create file

Comment: I want the file to be in .log or .txt format. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the WinAPI function [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the path of the temp directory.

Comment: I want the file to be in .log or .txt format. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `getenv()` to read the environment variable, then just figure out a filename and `fopen()` it, for example.

Note that the part where you "figure out a filename" is hard, it's better to use e.g. `mkstemp()` or `tmpfile()`.

Comment: +1 for the tmpfile() type functions.  Very useful, and very overlooked when needed.

Comment: The MSDN says about tmpfile: "This function is deprecated because a more secure version is available; see tmpfile_s." source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x7sakw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I want the file to be in .log or .txt format. How to do that?

Comment: .log or .txt don't have any "format". They are just ASCII characters. When you need to know how to write output to a file, you should create a new question for that (or better: google it, it's part of any complete C tutorial).

Answer (score -2):

```
char * pTemp;

pTemp = getenv ("TEMP"); /*Get temp folder path*/
if (pTemp!=NULL)
{
 printf ("Temp folder path is %s",pTemp);
}
```

Comment: Welcome toStackOverflow. This answer [has already been given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12302361/588306) with more context and explanation. If you have more to add, please update that answer rather than duplicating it. Thanks